# How do I synchronise the Preview pane to the Latex pane?

Tags: texstudio, live-preview

I have just gone back to using TexStudio and am using 6.4.3 on Monteroy (older Mac). In the previous software I was using, when I scrolled through my latex text, the preview would scroll with the text. If I clicked on a section heading or other heading, the preview would jump to that part of the document.

In TexStudio, the scrolling for both appears independent. Am I missing a setting? I've looked through the options and nothing appears obvious.

I have found that I can use the View icon to the right of the compile options in that menu bar.

Is there a way to turn the synchronisation on automatically rather than keep clicking View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the internal pdf viewer to follow the cursor in your tex file. This will automatically sync the pdf to whatever place you click in the tex code.

To do this, there is a button on the bottom left of the viewer:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly!

Comment: @Michelle You're welcome!